# Cannot add file or do anything after using git reset --hard

Tags: git

I used `git reset --hard <The commit's SHA>` to undo the commit. After that my console looks like this:

> `IP710s (master) Cat-clicker`

The asterisk(*) is disappeared from `(master)`. Then, I want to stage a file, after I used:

> `git add css/app.css` then `git status`

It display

> `On branch master`
>   `nothing to commit, working tree clean`

I expect my console to be like `IP710s (master *) Cat-clicker` , and be like `IP710s (master +) Cat-clicker` after I stage a file.

How to make it work again? I cannot stage and commit now?

Thank you.

Comment: Are there changes to be staged?  
run `git status` and make sure your changes are still there.

Comment: Did you modify files between doing your reset and adding? If not, the "clean tree" result is expected.

Comment: @TrentonTrama and RomainValeri, thanks so much for your answer. I forgot that reset command also remove all the change that unstaged. I redo the file, and I can stage and commit now.